# NYC general election mayor polls: have any been released in 2021?

Tags: united-states, election, public-opinion, local-government, new-york-city

I have been wondering about the NYC mayor election. I paid a lot of attention to this primary, which had one of the highest turnouts out of any NYC Democratic primary. However, now that the candidates have been decided, I have been wondering if there are any general election polls publicly available now. (I looked it up, and could not find any on Google search.) Have any general election polls for the NYC mayoral election been released so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the time that this question was posted - but a [poll was conducted](https://emersonpolling.reportablenews.com/pr/nyc-2021-adams-poised-to-be-next-mayor-of-nyc-leading-sliwa-by-40-points) between October 22nd and 23rd by Emerson College/PIX11/NewsNation which gave Eric Adams, the Democratic Party candidate, a 40-point lead over his Republican opponent, Curtis Sliwa.

> The Emerson College/PIX11/NewsNation poll of the New York City mayoral
> race finds Democrat Eric Adams leading Republican Curtis Sliwa 61% to
> 25% among likely voters. Fourteen percent (14%) are undecided. When
> the undecided voters are allocated towards the candidate they said
> they are leaning towards, Adams expands his lead to forty points, 70%
> to 30%.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Tl:dr According to one website, no polls have been released yet.

According to [Crowd Wisdom 360](https://crowdwisdom.live/us-politics/nyc-mayoral-polls-2021/)

> no NYC Mayoral Polls 2021 have been released yet

<sub>Disclaimer: I couldn’t find a fact check for this website, so it might be untrustworthy or false.</sub>